# Multiple dynamic ranges for printing

Tags: excel, range, offset, named-ranges

So I got this table:

[image: geo_table]

I need Excel to print different ranges on different sheet of papers. Ranges will always be different. I need A1 (range A2:B3) routes to print on one page and A2 (range A4:B5) routes print on second sheet of paper. And so on.

I'm thinking about creating another table on the right and defining the ranges of the route for example:

[image]

Then after I would use Name Manager to to give names to ranges in reference of for A1 route B13 cell.

But how do I return ranges where route matches?

Please advise if that is even a considerable idea? Or maybe there is something more efficient?

Comment: I don't think this can be done without VBA. Is this an available option for your application? You could make your full range into a table and then filter the table for each specific value, print the table and then restart filtering for a different value.

Comment: Actually I proved myself a liar. If your routes are ordered and the same route is listed consecutively there is a way to pull the ranges. Please review my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data is on columns A and B (I moved the second table to columns G and H) then in H2 you can place the array formula (`CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`):

```
="A"&MIN(IF(G2=$A:$A,ROW($A:$A),""))&":B"&MAX(IF(G2=$A:$A,ROW($A:$A),""))
```

This is also dependent on your data being all consecutive for each route (ie all A1's are together).